# Can gerrit support folder level permissions

Tags: git, gerrit

In my companies gerrit fileserver, there was previously only a single level with all the repositories inside. Now I have created a subdirectory git/MyGroup which contains repositories worked on and maintained by my group. Is there any capability to within this subdirectory create a second group of "administrators", so others can create repos and everyone within the group has read/write permission?

Currently I am the sole administrator in my group, but we work on a bunch of small discontinuous projects so I do not want to be in charge of repo creation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*First of all, Gerrit is not a 'fileserver' with permissions based on folders. It is a Git repository server and code review tool. And Git does not offer file/folder-level based access permissions, but rather based on a ref.*

I believe you're asking for way to control permissions based on the project (repository) *hierarchy*. That's certainly possible, using the *inherit* field in the permissions manager for a project.

[image]

E.g. set up a project structure like this:

- `All-Projects` - the default meta top-level project in Gerrit.
- `common/_base` - ACL-only base project, *inheriting* from `All-Projects`. It is defining the ACLs for repositories in `common/*`.
- `common/project1` - regular repository, inheriting from `common/_base`
- `common/project2` - regular repository, inheriting from `common/_base`
- `common/project3` - regular repository, inheriting from `common/_base`, but with some special ACLs specific to this, that's all right!

Then, on `common/_base`, you can set *additional* ACLs which will be applied to all those projects inheriting from it (and because that one in turn inherits from All-Projects, you'll get all of that applied together).

Note that the project/repository name ('directory') is not of any relevance, but inheritance is. While the project listing on the Web UI does not list them as a tree, you can print it using the SSH administrative command (`gerrit ls-projects --tree`). I just like to 'group' my repositories like the above naming scheme to indicate the category.

Comment: 'fileserver' does not mean permissions are based on folders. The problem here would be that certain groups have permissions from All-Projects that should not be included. An idea was floated of creating a separate "All-Projects" and using that, in a similar vein to here. Thank you for the answer!